# D3D11 increased ref count from nowhere?

Tags: c++, com, c++11, directx, direct3d11

I have been working with d3d11 for quite a while now, and after discovering the directx debugger, i've recently discovered that my program is leaking memory everywhere from all the com objects that aren't releasing properly. After a bit of snooping around and hours of staring at the code, i've developed some methods to isolate where i'm getting these unexpected increases to the ref counts.

first off, all of the objects are wrapped in std::shared_ptrs with custom deleters that call their respective release function. I did this so i would never have to call addref, and the first call to release, the one in the deleter, would only be called when the object went out of scope. It would look something like this:

```
// in D3D11Renderer.h
...
// declaration
std::shared_ptr<ID3D11Device *> m_Device;
...

// after call to ID3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain
m_Device.reset(device, [](ID3D11Device * ptr){ptr->Release();})
```

Problem is certain random functions in the api calls will just randomly increase the ref count, expecting me to have to deal with it later.

something i found useful in diagnosis was a function that looked like this:

```
template <typename T>
int getRefCount(T object) 
{
    object->AddRef();
    return object->Release();
}
```

which, just increments and decrements that count to obtain the current count of refs on that object. Using this, i found that, just before the release in the custom deleter is called, there are 10 outstanding references to the 1 ID3D11Device i created. Curious, i backtracked slowly, calling this function all the way back through the program, right up to  where i originally created it. Funny thing, just after i first create the object, (even before the shared_ptr takes ownership), the number of outstanding refs is already 3! This occurs immediately after this here.

```
result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, 0, &featureLevel, 1, 
                           D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &swapChain, &device, NULL, &deviceContext);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }
```

this is the first time i call any such function that creates the device, and when i check to see how many refs there are right after, and it says 3! So clearly, I'm misunderstanding something about the way these com objects are supposed to be handled. Is there any such way that i can just manually delete them, rather then use there behind-the-scenes ref counting nonsense?

Comment: If you manually deleted them while something else had a reference to them, your program would crash. The reference counts are higher because you've created new structures that hold references to your original structures. This is great though, you can release your reference and not worry about it, when the new structures are destroyed, then the old structures will drop their reference counts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every time you create a buffer or a shader or anything that depends on the device, that object will likely contain a reference to the device so will bump up it's reference count to ensure it's not deleted while it is still using it.

It sounds like your approach might well work overall, as you'll essentially keep one single reference to the device in your code to stop it being deleted, and when all your internal references are gone release it. However d3d will still be doing it's own reference counting and so the reference count will only drop to zero when you release every reference to every other related object. Even just creating the swap chain and device will make back buffers and so on that likely need to maintain a reference to the device.

I tried this same idea for a while... And in the end found it much easier to just

```
#include <atlbase>
```

Then use

```
CComPtr<ID311Device> m_Device
```

as that's pretty much exactly what that class is designed for and it's more lightweight than std::shader_ptr as the objects already have a reference counter in them so there is no need to keep a separate one.

Comment: i desperately wish to use the CComPtr object, but apparently it's not available in visual studio 2010 express edition. That's why i'm having to go roundabout with using std::shared_ptr. So basically what your saying is, if i can ensure the destruction of all the other d3d11 objects, then the release within the custom deleter should work fine? I guess i'll go hunting for the other object that aren't being destructed then. Thanks for the help! Also, is that "std::shader_ptr" a typo, or did you mean to write that?

Comment: That's a type, sorry. And oh, sorry I didn;'t know that wasn't available with the express version

Comment: typo... oops typical - It probably wouldn't be too hard to write a minimal replacement for CComPtr anyway, it's just a simple wrapper that calls Release and AddRef when appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Using shared_ptr is not correct for Direct3D (COM) objects, even if you use custom deleters.

First, COM objects use intrusive reference counting, which means the reference count is stored in the object itself. shared_ptr on the other hand uses non-intrusive reference counting, which means the reference count is stored in the smart poiter object. Therefore, using shared_ptr for COM objects means that you have two separate, independent reference counts: the COM object's, and the shared_ptr's.

Second, using a custom deleter solves the problem of properly releasing the object, but it doesn't solve the problem of properly acquiring a reference to the object. Assigning a COM object to a shared_ptr will increment the reference count of the shared_ptr, but not the object's.

That explains why you're leaking objects: D3D methods increment objects' reference counts, but you are using shared_ptrs that decrement the object's reference count only once for the entire lifetime of the object (when all shared_ptrs pointing to the object are destroyed).

So, you need to use a COM smart pointer, such as ATL's [CComPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: While I agree that using shared_ptr on COM objects is generally a bad idea, nested reference counting does not suffer the problem of leaking objects you described. In this case shared_ptr holds one reference of the COM object and the custom deleter frees it once all references to the shared_ptr object are gone, which is correct behavior. So even though its not good habit its still correct. The reason for the additional references are (as @J99 already pointed out) the dependencies between different COM objects.