# Release resources allocated with D3D11CreateDevice()

Tags: winapi, direct3d

Short question: after successfully calling D3D11CreateDevice(), I got back a HRESULT. At the very end of the related functionality: how do I release the resources allocated with this?

Comment: Each COM reference you get must be released, so in the D3D11CreateDevice case, pDevice-Release() and/or ppImmediateContext->Release()

Comment: The question is missing a great deal of detail. What are you doing with the device that comes back from ``D3D11CreateDevice``?  See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/prog-dx-with-com) for general guidelines.

Comment: And HRESULT is just a numeric value, it does not have associated resources.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn i dropped this part of the question as it is obviously: I want to release these D3D resources at the very end, so when this device is no longer used. So what I'm looking for is something like D3D11ReleaseDevice() to free all associated memory when this device is no longer used

Answer (score 1):

From [Managing Object Lifetimes Through Reference Counting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/managing-object-lifetimes-through-reference-counting), we can find a good explanation.

> It is important that an object be deallocated when it is no longer
> being used. The difficulty lies in determining when it is appropriate
> to deallocate an object. For COM objects, which are dynamically allocated, it
> is up to the clients of an object to decide when they no longer need
> to use the object—especially local or remote objects that might be in
> use by multiple clients at the same time. The object must wait until
> all clients are finished with it before freeing itself. Because COM
> objects are manipulated through interface pointers and can be used by
> objects in different processes or on other machines, the system cannot
> keep track of an object's clients.
>
> **COM's method of determining when it is appropriate to deallocate an
> object is manual reference counting. Each object maintains a reference
> count** that tracks how many clients are connected to it - that is, how
> many pointers exist to any of its interfaces in any client.

For more information, see: [Rules for Managing Reference Counts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/rules-for-managing-reference-counts)

> When implementing or using reference-counted objects, it may be useful
> to apply artificial reference counts, which guarantee object stability
> during processing of a function. In implementing a method of an
> interface, you might call functions that have a chance of decrementing
> your reference count to an object, causing a premature release of the
> object and failure of the implementation. **A robust way to avoid this
> is to insert a call to AddRef at the beginning of the method
> implementation and pair it with a call to Release just before the
> method returns.**

Another link that may be useful to you: [D3D11 increased ref count from nowhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644380/d3d11-increased-ref-count-from-nowhere)

Comment: For DirectX 10/DirectX 11, keep in mind that no device child object out-lives it's parent deivice. If the device refcount goes to 0, they are all invalid.