# Release memory aquired by CreateTexture2D()?

Tags: textures, direct3d, direct3d11

as the MSDN is not very specific at this point: in my application I create a texture by calling CreateTexture2D().

On success, do I have to release the created texture? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** This is documented on MSDN in this article: [Programming DirectX with COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/prog-dx-with-com)

Direct3D uses COM reference-counting for lifetime management.

- All the objects are derived from `IUnknown` and when they are created have a refcount of 1.
- When you call `Release` it decrements the refcount. Once the refcount is 0, the object is eligible for cleaning up all it's memory and resource use. For performance reasons, Direct3D uses deferred destruction so typically all these objects are cleaned up a frame or two later.

> Once the "external" refcount is 0, the Direct3D Runtime will deal with cleaning it up. You don't have to do anything else. If you want to *force* all deferred destruction, you can use `ID3D11DeviceContext::Flush`, but you shouldn't do it often as it severely impacts performance.

- If you want to have more than one pointer reference the same object, you call `AddRef` to increment it's refcount.
- For Direct3D 10, 11, and 12, there is a slight modification of the COM lifetime rules. Specifically, if a "device" hits a refcount of 0, then all "device child objects" created from that device are invalid even if *their* refcount is non-zero.
- For Direct3D 10, 11, and 12, if you 'bind' an object to the rendering pipeline, this *does not* increment the refcount. You have to ensure the object remains valid until the rendering is complete. See [Reference Counting (Direct3D 10)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d10/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-api-features-reference-counting).

For C++ development, the strong recommendation is to use a COM smart-pointer of some kind to automatically increment/decrement refcounts as needed. Options here include:

- WRL's `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr`**
- C++/WinRT's `winrt::com_ptr`
- WIL's `wil::com_ptr`

For completeness there is also:

- ATL's `CComPtr` (*WRL is basically "ATL 2.0", and ATL is only installed with Visual Studio as an opt-in feature*)
- Visual Studio's `_com_ptr_t` (*a half-hearted attempt, so not a great choice*)

> ** =  This is my preference currently since it's available in the Windows 8.0 SDK or later and works for Win32 desktop, UWP, and Xbox. See [DirectX Tool Kit Wiki: ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) for reasoning and examples.

See also [MSDN: Managing Object Lifetimes Through Reference Counting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/managing-object-lifetimes-through-reference-counting) and [Wikipedia: Reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting)

Comment: Note that per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060481/release-resources-allocated-with-d3d11createdevice), ``ID3D11Device`` is itself derived from ``IUnknown`` and also uses COM refcounts.